# OpenVPN on mobile

Tags: mobile, openvpn

I recently installed openVPN on my phone. I set it up at home and `whatsmyip` showed my vpn server's ip on both my desktop and on my mobile device (connected to home wifi)

When I am on a mobile network, `whatsmyip` shows an ipv6 address. I connect to the vpn (using OpenVPN for Android) and it shows a successful connection, although `whatsmyip` shows the same ipv6 address.

Is something configured wrong? Any more detrministic checks I can make other than checking my ip address via the Google tool?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich ah, didn't see your answer for some reason

Answer (score 3):

There is a common problem that several VPN setups do not properly deal with IPv6. A [study from 2015](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/06/30/worlds_best_vpns_fall_flat_in_security_tests/) found that 10 of 14 VPN providers leaked IPv6 addresses, i.e. that only IPv4 traffic was actually covered by the VPN.

And while current versions of OpenVPN support IPv6 it must be available and [properly configured](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IPv6) at the server too. If the server has only IPv4 support configured it will not push a IPv6 route to the VPN client which means that all IPv6 traffic will bypass the VPN.

Comment: Dang that's a security hole, right? Ha openvpn for android app didn't even tell me something was wrong (if it did, that info was not slammed in my face like I think it should have been)

Comment: User interface issue rather that hole per se. But still

Comment: https://github.com/jlund/streisand/issues/97 I used Streisand to set up my vpn server. There is currently an open issue addressing this

Comment: @BrianLeach: I'm not sure how much trust I have in a VPN setup which leaves a known major bypass unaddressed for 2 years.